# Django, how to fetch username and password and pass to other application

Tags: django, authentication

I'm running a Django app which is integrated with login. Authenticated via done via LDAP. This web front post data to another application server via REST API. Currently, authentication is done via static to post data. But I would like to use the same credentials which users use to log in the front web, which is their user LDAP. 
How to pass the user and pass into python script to post the data on to another server?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You also should not be storing raw passwords anywhere... does the API provide other authentication methods? When you say post data, do you mean a basic auth header or in the post data body itself?

Comment: basic auth header

Comment: is there anyway to pass in the current user session into the python script?

Comment: How is the API being called, where is this script? Is it in a Django view?

Comment: Yes, I call the script in the view.py

Comment: The way script works, main function fetch the `os.environ.get` within that file has the username and password.. I was thinking to pass the username and pass, when I call the script in the view.